# Bash script in the file do nothing when executed in IntelliJ IDEA + Windows

Tags: bash, shell, intellij-idea, window

The simplest script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello!
```

If I run it by IntelliJ IDEA + Windows:

[image]

It does not print anything:

```
PS D:\IntelliJ IDEA\XXX\Components\StylesApplying> "D:/IntelliJIDEA/XXX/Components/StylesApplying/
test.bash"
D:/IntelliJ IDEA/XXX/Components/StylesApplying/test.bash
```

[image]

Of course I need the solution, but first please explain me WHY it does not work as expected.

By the way, adding the double quotes to "Hello!" does not change anything.

Also, I have tried other scripts with same zero result.

Comment: I'm not that much specialist for Windows, but AFIK, either Windows or your IDE need to know that they have to use `bash.exe` to run a script. Under Windows, this is usually done by associating a file extension (in your case: `.bash`) with the absolute path of the bash executable. This is explained [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000572.htm). An IDE too should provide in its preferences to define such an association. Perhaps you did not do any of this? Can you run your script from a Windows CMD prompt?

Comment: In addition to above. You can try using bash.exe from the Git installation to run bash files from Windows. (C:/Program Files/Git/bin) To configure it in IntelliJ IDEA you either need to configure shell path under "Settings | Tools | Terminal | Shell Path" or create a new [Shell Script](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) run configuration and specify the path to the bash.exe here and path to your script

Comment: @EgorKlepikov Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, it does not work, however because it is another error I need to consider it in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash is not part of Windows.

You have to fully reference a bash implementation like **Bash for Windows**, **Bash by CYGWIN**, or run the script a
under **WSL**.